# How to ensure all consumers consume messages from all partitions in a multi-consumer setup with Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a Kafka cluster set up with 10 brokers and a single topic containing 15 partitions. In our application, we're running 15 consumer instances in parallel using Spring Kafka. However, when polling messages, we've noticed that only 10 consumers are consuming messages, leaving some partitions underutilized.

We suspect that there might be some configuration assumptions that we're overlooking. How can we ensure that all 15 consumers effectively consume data from all 15 partitions? Our goal is to maximize the consumption throughput and evenly distribute the workload across all consumers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need 15 consumer instances, but just one `@KafkaListener` with `concurrency = 15`. All your brokers in that cluster must be present in the `bootstrapServers` configuration property.

If that is not the case, would be great to see some code from you.